# Sine Wave Curve Fitting in Java

Tags: java, math, apache-commons, curve-fitting

I'm using the [Apache Commons Math](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/index.html) package and I've got the following Sine Wave...

```
  0.90, 0.85, 0.80, 0.83, 0.89
  0.90, 0.85, 0.80, 0.83, 0.89
  0.90, 0.85, 0.80, 0.83, 0.89
  0.90, 0.85, 0.80, 0.83, 0.89
```

from the above data you can see that the wave has the following attributes...

- Amplitude = `.05`
- Phase = `0`
- Frequency = `5`

However, when I add my sine wave to a `HarmonicFitter` like so...

```
HarmonicFitter fitter = new HarmonicFitter(new LevenbergMarquardtOptimizer());

fitter.addObservedPoint(0, 0.90);
fitter.addObservedPoint(1, 0.85);
fitter.addObservedPoint(2, 0.80);
fitter.addObservedPoint(3, 0.83);
fitter.addObservedPoint(4, 0.89);

fitter.addObservedPoint(5, 0.90);
fitter.addObservedPoint(6, 0.85);
fitter.addObservedPoint(7, 0.80);
fitter.addObservedPoint(8, 0.83);
fitter.addObservedPoint(9, 0.89);

fitter.addObservedPoint(10, 0.90);
fitter.addObservedPoint(11, 0.85);
fitter.addObservedPoint(12, 0.80);
fitter.addObservedPoint(13, 0.83);
fitter.addObservedPoint(14, 0.89);

fitter.addObservedPoint(15, 0.90);
fitter.addObservedPoint(16, 0.85);
fitter.addObservedPoint(17, 0.80);
fitter.addObservedPoint(18, 0.83);
fitter.addObservedPoint(19, 0.89);

double[] vals = fitter.fit();

return vals;
```

The values returned are more like...

```
Amplitude: 5.19813329138371
Frequency: 4.69209750375546E-5
Phase: 1.405312649084833
```

Why has the curve fitting resulted in such drastically different attributes for a sinewave with 4 identical frequencies?

Comment: Could it be simply because your data points are not precise enough?

Comment: Are you sure that you print these values correctly? Your amplitude seems to have the value of frequency, frequency of phase and so on

Comment: @lejlot I would think so, Amplitude = vals[0] according to the Javadoc.

Comment: +1; this is the most complete, well formatted, grammatically correct question I have seen in a few days.

Comment: @LordOfThePigs I'm not quite sure what you mean by your comment?

Comment: Also, I find it weird that your observed points are periodical on a cycle of 5, given that you say the frequency is 5, shouldn't the periodicity of your samples be PI/5?

Comment: What you have is not a sine wave, it is a superposition of a sine wave on a constant, where the constant is much more dominant. Is your math API expected to compensate for that?

Comment: @Skizit: you give each of you datapoint to 2 digits precision. Is this really the exact value at that point, or are there actually more decimals? Couldn't it be that the fitter finds a much weirder looking sine that passes exactly through the points you specified (with 2 digits decimals) instead of the points you intended to specify (which actually have more decimals than that).

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: Seems the fitter tries to fit the following function:  φ: f (t) = a cos (ω t + φ)  So that would be no.

Comment: @LordOfThePigs Well, that is surely the most prominent issue, then.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be mixing up order of the output and not mapping it correctly to labels (`fit`returns an array).

The values that you obtained really reflect your inputs:

Try to draw your values on paper and put a sinewave on them -- your assertions of 0.5 for amplitude and 5 for frequency are incorrect. The phase is Ok, which is confirmed by 4.69e-5. Your frequency is well above 5. The amplitude of 0.5 is what you want, not what the data shows, 1.4: because there are no points on the downslope of the sine the optimiser actuyally thinks that points 0.8, 0.83 and 0.89 all belong to the upslope of the sinewave with a much larger amplitude -- this reduces the error.

All in all, you are overfitting by trying to fit 3 values with essentially 5 points.

Answer (score 2):

@Marko Topolnik has the problem.  The `Fitter` is expecting a simple harmonic (i.e., a single cosine or sine), which has mean zero.  So subtract `0.854` (the mean) from everything, and add that constant back to your resulting sine wave.

As things are, the tiny frequency is giving a flat sine wave, so the other numbers are irrelevant.  Try plotting everything (including the resulting function).

---

**Edit:** Here are two plots.  The first has your points along with three functions: your desired `y=.05*cos(2πx/5)`, the same function plus `.0854` (it appears your phase won't be zero), and the package's best fit function:
[image: picture of best fits]
  But you can't distinguish the package's best fit function until you zoom way out to a window of `[-1e5,1e5]x[-8,8]`:
[image: same picture, dramatically scaled out horizontally]
This also means that the package's best fit function is wildly unstable.  A small change in your points will cause a large change in the output.