# How do I fit a sine curve to my data in Java?

Tags: java, least-squares, trigonometry

I've spend a few days trying to get this exact same code running in java: [How do I fit a sine curve to my data with pylab and numpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16716302/how-do-i-fit-a-sine-curve-to-my-data-with-pylab-and-numpy)

Based on this answer: [Sine Wave Curve Fitting in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20951640/sine-wave-curve-fitting-in-java), I've started putting together this code:

```
public double sine_fit(double[] current_sample){
        double[] half_cycle = Arrays.copyOfRange(current_sample, 175, 225);
        double amp = 3*ArrayUtils.std(half_cycle)/Math.sqrt(2);
        double freq = 0;
        double phase = 0;
        double[] guess = new double[]{amp, freq, phase};
        HarmonicCurveFitter curveFit = new HarmonicCurveFitter(new LevenbergMarquardtOptimizer());
        //curveFit.withStartPoint(guess);
        for (int i=0; i < half_cycle.length; i++) {
            curveFit.addObservedPoint(i, half_cycle[i]);
        }
        double[] vals = curveFit.fit();
        System.out.println(vals);
    }
```

It doesn't compile, and it's not quite what I want (i.e., exactlty what's in the first link)

I'd really appreciate some help. Not being able to do in Java what I can do with only a few lines in Python is driving me nuts.

P.S.: Long time Python coder, newbee Java programmer.

## Update

Based on @17slim's answer:

```
    double[] half_cycle = Arrays.copyOfRange(current_sample, 175, 225);
    double amp = 3*ArrayUtils.std(half_cycle)/Math.sqrt(2);
    double freq = 0;
    double phase = 0;
    double[] guess = new double[]{amp, freq, phase};
    HarmonicCurveFitter curveFit = HarmonicCurveFitter.create();
    curveFit.withStartPoint(guess);
    List<WeightedObservedPoint> points = new ArrayList<WeightedObservedPoint>();
    for (int i=0; i < half_cycle.length; i++) {
        points.add(new WeightedObservedPoint(1.0, i, half_cycle[i]));
    }
    double[] vals = curveFit.fit(points);
    for (double val: vals){
        System.out.println(val);
    }
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: - Cannot resolve method `addObservedPoint`  
- Constructor HarmonicCurveFitter in class org.apache.commons.math3.fitting.HarmonicCurveFitter cannot be applied to given types; required: double[],int found: org.apache.commons.math3.fitting.leastsquares.LevenbergMarquardtOptimizer    
- Method fit in class org.apache.commons.math3.fitting.AbstractCurveFitter cannot be applied to given types; required: java.util.Collection<org.apache.commons.math3.fitting.WeightedObservedPoint> found: no arguments

Comment: what is HarmonicCurveFitter? I can't seem to find a reference for that anywhere

Comment: `import org.apache.commons.math3.fitting.HarmonicCurveFitter;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HarmonicCurveFitter` does not extend `CurveFitter`; it extends `AbstractCurveFitter`, which does not have method `addObservedPoint`.  `GaussianFitter`, `HarmonicFitter`, and `PolynomialFitter` are the known extenders of `CurveFitter`, which has the required method. Use `HarmonicFitter`.

See: [CurveFitter](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.5/org/apache/commons/math3/fitting/CurveFitter.html) and [HarmonicCurveFitter](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.5/org/apache/commons/math3/fitting/HarmonicCurveFitter.html)

EDIT:
Since `HarmonicFitter` is deprecated, you are correct to use `HarmonicCurveFitter`. Since it doesn't have the method you need, use `fit(Collection<WeightedObservedPoint> points)` instead of `addObservedPoint`.

Instead do:

```
HarmonicCurveFitter curveFit = new HarmonicCurveFitter.create();
List<WeightedObservedPoint> points = new ArrayList<WeightedObservedPoint>();
for (int i=0; i < half_cycle.length; i++) {
    points.add(new WeightedObservedPoint(1.0, i, half_cycle[i]));
}
double[] vals = curveFit.fit(points);
```

From the documentation:

> The default implementation uses a Levenberg-Marquardt optimizer.

Make sure to import `org.apache.commons.math3.fitting.WeightedObservedPoint`, `org.apache.commons.math3.fittingHarmonicCurveFitter`, `java.util.List` and `java.util.ArrayList`.

Also, printing `vals` does not print each value like in Python, it prints a pointer to the array. Use `for (double val: vals)` and display each value individually.

Comment: `HarmonicFitter` seems to be deprecated. I'm supposed to use `HarmonicCurveFitter` and `WeightedObservedPoints`. I tried, and that also didn't go too far.

Comment: You are correct, but it will work in exactly the same way. I'll try to find an undeprecated equivalent.

Comment: Ok, from the documentation: `As of 3.3. Please use HarmonicCurveFitter and WeightedObservedPoints instead.`

Comment: So, you are correct to use `HarmonicCurveFitter`, but since it doesn't have the required method, you should implement it instead with `fit(Collection<WeightedObservedPoint> points)`

Comment: Awesome! That works!!! Last think I need to figure out is the least square step. What I was trying with the `LevenbergMarquardtOptimizer()`. And how to get back a sine array, instead of just the parameters.

Comment: Edited to include info about the optimizer

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have to use `HarmonicFitter` class and the method of that class - `addObservedPoint`.
Neither the class `HarmonicCurveFitter` nor his parent `AbstractCurveFitter` do not contain method `addObservedPoint`.